# Android: Get size of Wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

I want to have the default size of the Wallpaper for the Crop Intent.
Because then the user can crop the Image to the right size for the Wallpaper.

I tried it with

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDrawable().getMinimumHeight();//same for width
```

or

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDesiredMinimumHeight();//same for width
```

but on the Samsung Galaxy S4 mini it says 960x960 and this can't be.
On my HTC One V it says 960x800 this could be, but I think this isn't exactly correct.

Do you know any way to find the Wallpaper size?
It isn't enough to have the Screen Dimensions, because e.g. my HTC Wallpaper is bigger than the screen because the Wallpaper moves if you wipe to the left or the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting your Wallpaper to a Drawable and then get the width and height from it :

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
Drawable d = wpm.getDrawable();
int width = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

or cast to a Bitmap :

```
bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
width = bmp.getWidth();
height = bmp.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your question, you need an image which will fit properly on home screen.
See below links :

1. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-is-the-default-resolution-of-a-wallpaper-that-fits-the-homescreen-exactly-i
2. http://lifehacker.com/5657727/whats-the-deal-with-androids-weird-wallpaper-requirements

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Okay thank you the second link is helpful but it says Android needs the width*2 but on the Samsung GS4 Mini and S3 Mini (for example) the Wallpaper is fixed. I'll try it with 2*width but I think on those smartphones it wont work.